# Select the current row in a cell of jqxDataTable in jwidgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm new with jwidgets I just wanted to ask how do I select the current row in a cell of table example the schedule_id jqxDataTable, your help is much appreciated. The code of my data table.

```
function table_data(){
        var name = $("#id_name").val();
        var url = "http://bodyline###/###/myschedule?name="+name;
        // prepare the data
        var source =
        {
            dataType: "json",
            dataFields: [
                { name: 'schedule_id', type: 'int' },
                { name: 'status', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'day', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'start_am', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'end_am', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'start_pm', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'end_pm', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'dob', type: 'string' }
            ],
            id: 'id',
            url: url
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable(
        {
            width: 920,
            pageable: true,
            pagerButtonsCount: 10,
            source: dataAdapter,
            columnsResize: true,
            columns: [
              { text: 'CONTROL',            dataField: 'schedule_id',   width: 70 },
              { text: 'STATUS',             dataField: 'status',        width: 150 },
              { text: 'DAYS',               dataField: 'day',           width: 180 },
              { text: 'MORNING IN',         dataField: 'start_am',      width: 120 },
              { text: 'MORNING OUT',        dataField: 'end_am',        width: 120},
              { text: 'AFTERNOON IN',       dataField: 'start_pm',      width: 140 },
              { text: 'AFTERNOON OUT',      dataField: 'end_pm',        width: 140},
              { text: 'DATE',               dataField: 'dob',           width: 120 }
          ]
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This event is row click

```
         $('#dataTable').on('rowClick', 
            function (event)
            {
                var args = event.args;
                var row = args.row;
                var index = args.index;
                var boundIndex = args.boundIndex; 
                var key = args.key;
                var dataField = args.dataField;
                var clickEvent = args.originalEvent;
                var value = $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable('getCellValue', index, 'schedule_id');
                alert(value);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of $(this) for example

```
    $("#dataTable").click(function() {
      var parentRowCss = $(this).getGridParam("schedule_id"); 
    }
```

Comment: the output in alert is [object Object] :(

Comment: I wanted to get the current schedule_id of the cell I double click

Comment: var parentRowCss = $(this);  
       $("#dataTable").click(function(){
           alert( parentRowCss );//Current Row in cell 
       });

Comment: I think i need declaration or method or something for Event and Arguments in C# its easy but jwidgets I just dont know how :(

Comment: its already but thanks anyway I already got the correct answer.